# Pig unable to create .bz2 files but creating .deflate files

Tags: hdfs, apache-pig, deflate, bzip2, hdp

Here is by pig script which I am using to read, filter and then compress data in bzip2 but I am getting .deflate files instead of .bz2.

```
set output.compression.enabled true;
set output.compression.codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec;
inputFile = LOAD '/dl/myfolder/' using PigStorage('|') AS (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,clo6,col7,col8,col9,col10);
filteredFile = FILTER inputFile BY col7 is not null;
store filteredFile into '/dl/myfolder/compressdata/' USING PigStorage('|');

Output file /dl/myfolder/compressdata/part-m-00000.deflate
```

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regret could not update as this issue we faced when upgrading from pivotal to hortonworks. And found out that
mapreduce.map.output.compress = true
mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress = true
These overrides the in session output format and always compresses.
After setting them to false we got the desired output

Thanks Koji/John for your time and valuable inputs.

Koji to your suggestion we have older design and everything is using bzip2 so changing to Lzo would be possible in next upgrade :)

Comment: map output compression (to lzo) wouldn't be visible to you since it's only about intermediate outputs.

Answer (score -1):

Please try changing your output directory name to end with bz2 (or bz).

```
store filteredFile into '/dl/myfolder/compressdata.bz2/' USING PigStorage('|');
```

Comment: Hmm. which version of pig are you using?  Also, you can take out output.compression.enabled/output.compression.codec once you have your output dir ends with bz2.

Comment: I figured out that you need something like SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec'; in addition to SET mapred.map.output.compress.codec 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec'; and SET mapred.output.compression.codec 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec';

Comment: I am using Apache Pig version 0.15.0

Comment: Again, try taking all out and just set the output path to bz2.  That should set the necessary config for bzip compression.  Also, you usually don't want map output compression to be bzip2.  For intermediate output compression, you want something faster like lzo, etc.